# Event handling not working in Python 3.3.0?

Tags: python

I tried running the chapter 15 programs that came with Object-Oriented Programming in Python by Goldwasser & Letscher. Chapter 15 deals with event handling. For some reason, it won't work. It always crashes the program when I run it. My Python version is 3.3.0 and the specific code is the following:

```
from cs1graphics import *

class BasicHandler(EventHandler):
  def handle(self, event):
    print( 'Event Triggered')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  simple = BasicHandler()
  paper = Canvas()
  paper.addHandler(simple)
```

When I run this program, it crashes Python immediately. Why's that?

EDIT: I downloaded Python 2.7.3 just to try this out in that version and it worked! So the problem is that there's something different in Python 3.3.0 that's causing this program to crash, but I haven't got a clue as to what is or should be different. Please help!

Comment: "crashes"?  Can you provide details?

Comment: @Ned Batchelder, when I run this program through IDLE, it opens up the canvas, and it stays loading. When I move my mouse pointer over it, its icon changes to the loading icon. If I click it or let it run for a bit, its title says, in parenthesis, Not Responding. This program is supposed to print "Event Triggered" on to the screen if I clicked anywhere on the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manny,

The latest version of cs1graphics (v 1.2a) adds support for Python 3, but it is still an alpha release. It has support for most of the Ch. 3 material from our book, but the event handling material from chapter 15 is not yet fully supported. Also, there is more risk of problem when running the event handling examples in IDLE, as IDLE is also a Tkinter app monitoring events.

You could use one of our earlier stable releases with Python 2.x if you want to explore those features.

You are also welcome to email us your current bug report at bugs@cs1graphics.org, as that may help us improve the latest version.